# Sensor for turning rail direction

Tags: sensors, arduino-motor-shield, stepper

I am trying to control an actuator carrying a carriage made from stepper motor. My problem is that after the carriage reach certain height, I want it to delay for several minutes and change direction to move the other way around.

Any suggestion on what sensor to use? I tried to use EndStop switch like the one in 3D printer but I haven't found any luck as it simply cuts the electronic connections once the carriage hits it.

Comment: Sounds like it depends on your mechanical setup, but how about a microswitch? Or a hall-effect sensor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a microprocessor, specifically an Arduino, then what you need to do is send the signal from the 'switch' (as defined by Mark Smith) into a digital input port and then let the Arduino make the electronics pause before reversing.  From you post it sounds like (and I am probably wrong) you have put the switch in between the power source and the actuator.

[image]

(Diagram by Majenko)

Comment: I usually use [draw.io](http://draw.io) for my block diagrams. Gives much more professional looking results with less effort ;) Like this: http://majenko.co.uk/resources/Stuff.png

Comment: @Majenko - Shhh.. don't tell anyone but I'm at work and was limited to Word.  :)  I'll check it out, thanks.

Comment: It's a website. No need to be "limited" these days ;)

Comment: Thank you!! I just tried it last night with 'switch' and it works beautifully